# Making of an option selected in ajax call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried below lines of code for making an option selected if it matches with the data's DepartmentName. It's not working. Please help !!!

```
         function fillDepartments(selectedText)
  {
        $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?action=fetchAllDepartments',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data:{},
                    success: function(data){
                        for(var i in data){
                                $('#employee_department').append('<option value="'+data[i]['_id']['$oid']+ '">'
                                  + data[i]['DepartmentName'] + selectedText == data[i]['DepartmentName'] ? "selected" : "" +
                                 '</option>');
                            }
                     }
              });                  
  }
```

Comment: what is not working ...its not fetching data or not selecting value after data fetched from server

Comment: yes ajax call is fetching data accurately but dropdown is filled with nothing despite having three items  in data

Comment: check the answer , seems like issue as you put selected between opening and closing bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a simple `if-else` condition:-

```
for(var i in data){
    if(selectedText == data[i]['DepartmentName']){
        $('#employee_department').append('<option value="'+data[i]['_id']['$oid']+ '" selected>'+ data[i]['DepartmentName']+'</option>');
    }else{
        $('#employee_department').append('<option value="'+data[i]['_id']['$oid']+ '">'+ data[i]['DepartmentName'] +'</option>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

seems like problem with below code where you are closing tag without including select in it

```
$('#employee_department').append('<option value="'+data[i]['_id']['$oid']+ '">'
  //error as its out of opening bracket 
  + data[i]['DepartmentName'] + selectedText == data[i]['DepartmentName'] ? "selected" : "" +'</option>');
```

you need to include selected in bracket5

```
<option value='abc' selected></option>
```

in your case it is

```
<option value='abc' > selected</option>//wrong
```